# Sitecore: Problems in accessing an Item in a particular language

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have an Item in sitecore with id '`{05B1C498-39D1-40D6-B454-2A3277A6DDF9}`' which has one language version in "`en`" and one in "`da-DK`" .

For this Item there is a field "`Test`" with type `text`, In English version I have saved "English Text" in this field. And for Danish version of above item I have saved "Danish Text" in the field "`Test`".

I want to get the the above item in Danish language. I used this code:

```
string dicItemId= "{05B1C498-39D1-40D6-B454-2A3277A6DDF9}"
Item dictionaryItem = Context.Database.GetItem(dicItemId, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("da-DK"));

lblTest.Text = dictionaryItem["Test"];
```

**I am expecting to see the string "Danish Text" for the above label. But somehow its not getting the Danish version and output is "English Text".**

I also tried to get the version of above item in a language whose version does not exist in my Sitecore, I tried with:

```
Item dictionaryItem = Context.Database.GetItem(dicItemId, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("nl-NL"));
```

I was expecting the `dictionaryItem` as `null` but still it contains the item with id '`{05B1C498-39D1-40D6-B454-2A3277A6DDF9}`'

Comment: Is the site utilizing language fallback?  https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/modules/language_fallback.aspx

Comment: No the website is not using language fallback.

Comment: Long shot - Have you tried publishing your system/languages/ folder?

Comment: @IanGraham Yes. its already published. Few seconds ago I used `contextDatabase.GetItem(dicItemId, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage("da"))`. And It worked now. But when I use "`da-DK`" then it doesn't work.

Comment: Danish language is actually named "da" by default in Sitecore - so might explain why it works..

Comment: Do you have any idea where can I get the languages and there codes ? Because this list is not valid for sitecore. [Table of Language Culture Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, try the following steps:

- Ensure that the Item is published in the "da-DK" language.
- The field is not [shared]

Context.Database.GetItem(..) will always return the Item (provided it exists), even when it does not include a specific language version.

Try the following simple test to ensure the item in your language is published:

[image]